# Why is a string inside of parentheses treated like a string and not a tuple?

Tags: python, string, tuples

I was working on some code when I realized I had changed a mutli-member tuple to a single-value string but left the parens wrapped around the string, and was surprised that I hadn't encountered any problems when I realized I had left in the parens.

Simple question, why are strings inside of parens treated as strings and not tuples?

I understand this:

```
>>> foo= 'bar'
>>> type(foo)
<class 'str'>
```

And I understand this:

```
>>> foo = ('bar',)
>>> type(foo)
<class 'tuple'>
```

And this, of course:

```
foo = ('bar', 'baz')
>>> type(foo)
<class 'tuple'>
```

But I don't understand this:

```
>>> foo = ('bar')
>>> type(foo)
<class 'str'>
```

Why is `('bar')` a string and not a tuple?  I know adding the trailing `,` makes it a tuple, but for what reason was that design decision made?

Comment: It is the **comma** that makes something a tuple. The parentheses are only there to disambiguate from other contexts where a comma might have a different meaning.

Comment: What about `x = (4 * 5) - 3`?  Would you want `(4 * 5)` to be a tuple?

Comment: @MartijnPieters You beat me to it. I was going to use this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682093/returning-tuple-with-a-single-item-from-a-function. Yours is more to the point.

Comment: You can go through this once :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19442556/distinction-between-python-str-and-tuple-objects

Comment: Okay, that makes sense and I see how this is a duplicate... but what about `foo = () `? Why does that return a tuple?  Seems like it should return NoneType?

Comment: @LegendaryDude: why? `()` is a valid tuple literal.

Comment: @vaultah `()` is a valid tuple literal, `('foo')` is a string literal, and `('foo',)` is a valid tuple literal. One of these things is not like the others.  I just don't quite get it -- was hoping for an explanation of why it is this way but it doesn't look like it's going to be anything other than "because."

Comment: `(None,)` would be a tuple with just `None` in it.  Python doesn't just make things `None` if they aren't there.  If something is `None`, that means something set it to `None`.  In the case of `()`, nothing did.  Since `()` doesn't really have much use besides making an empty tuple, it seems like a perfectly good way to do it.  What would you have otherwise? `(,)`?

Comment: @zondo At least that would be consistent with other tuple declarations?

Comment: Doesn't it seem sort of redundant to have the comma?  In the case of `(myexpression)`, the parentheses are acting as a way of containing an expression, but in the case of `()`, I don't see any use except to create an empty tuple.

Comment: @zondo I understand that, but if `()` is an empty tuple and `(1,)` is a tuple containing `1`, should not `(1)` also be a tuple containing `1`?  From a certain perspective, `()` should behave the same way regardless of how it is used.

Comment: @LegendaryDude: it should, but Python uses parentheses to group expressions.

Comment: `(1)` would be a perfectly good way to create a tuple except for the fact that parentheses are used to group expressions.  To differentiate between grouping and tuple-creating, you need a comma to create a tuple.  Such differentiation is not needed either for an empty tuple nor a tuple with more than one item.

Comment: @vaultah As long as I'm not the only one who thinks that logically they ought to, then it's alright with me.  I understand the considerations taken to make it all work.  Thanks for the insight, everyone.